# changing URL but want to send data to controller

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

My web application has a new requirement that if parameter coming in url then land to email page. otherwise on index page like always.
Its a very old client product and not much scope to change lot in  code so i put a check in controller that if encrypted email coming in then land to email page.
example url -

```
http://localhost:8080/R2/Controller?email=jAOtTv22BfkTkVrhTN/RHQ==
```

Everything works fine but i want to change URL.
How can i get rid of " /Controller " in URL but still it hits to controller.???

Controller code like -

```
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Controller.class);

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        // get the action property from the request
        String theAction = request.getParameter("action");
        String theSource = request.getParameter("s");
        String theSource1 = request.getParameter("email");

        String em ="";


        Action action=null;
       em = EncryptEmail.decrypt(theSource1,GFWConstants.BLOWFISH_KEY);

         if (em.equals(""))
                 rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp?emailRtv=0");
             else
                 rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("email-preferences.jsp?emailRtv=2&emailAddress="+em);

             rd.forward(request,response);
             return;
         }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the url-pattern of controller in web.xml

Comment: if i will change in web.xml then many pages are not working as all of then not landing to this page.

Comment: look into a url rewriting filter

Comment: or, give the servlet TWO url-patterns in the web.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding two url-pattern to web.xml file  worked.